# Role of Intermediate Filaments in cell - cell signalling

Tags: cytoskeleton

A passage in my textbook mentions briefly that the role of intermediate filaments in the cytoskeleton is to *enable cell to cell signalling by extending between special junctions and alowing cells to adhere to basement membrane*

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are desmosomes and gap junctions (cell-cell-contact), and hemidesmosomes (cell-basal membrane-contact) which enable a stable united cell structure. I'm not so aware with this topic, but I found some papers which may help you :)

[Intermediate filament in cell architecture](http://www.nature.com/nrm/journal/v8/n7/full/nrm2197.html)

[Desmosomes and hemidesmosomes](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0955067405800055)

[Review on gap junctions](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/09687680210139839)

[Blood-testis barrier and different cell-cell-contact structures](http://dx.doi.org/10.4161/spmg.1.2.15745)